# How to correctly refactor a control's namespace in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, refactoring

I have this situation which is rather frustrating... I have some user controls where I would like to rename their namespace.  However, when I do this my build fails because the .designer.cs file for pages that use the controls is still generating control declarations with the OLD namespace.  Is this coming from the assembly?  I can't rebuild because this is obviously creating a compile-time error (those controls no longer exist in the old name).  I've tried wiping out the entire file, but it is always regenerated with the old namespace.

How do I get around this without manually editing every .designer.cs file???

Comment: BTW... I am registering the controls with TagName, TagPrefix, and Src, so I don't know why it would even be looking at the assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I have used these steps with some success, but I've also had to monkey around a lot, so I maybe missing some steps. (its been a while since I had to deal with this issue)

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete all designer.cs files (backup just in case ;))
3. Fire up Visual Studio again and try a rebuild

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing something similar by blanking the files, deleting the assembly, and then touching all the .aspx files.  Ugh.